# Let $V = \{ f:[0,1] \to \Bbb{R} \text{, $f $ has a local Maxima at $x= 1/2$}\}$ over $\Bbb{R}$. Is $V$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = \{ f:[0,1] \to \Bbb{R} \text{, $f $ has a local Maxima at $x= 1/2$}\}$ over $\Bbb{R}$. Is $V$ a vector space?

First of all, I don't know if zero function has local extrema or not?

Second, if $f$ and $g$ have a local Maxima at $x=1/2$ then, what is the behaviour of $f+g$ at $ x=1/2$?

I think $x=1/2$ is also a point of local Maxima for $f+g.$

Third, is $V$ satisfying the property of scalar multiplication?

I have doubts in first two properties.
Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: I suppose technically the zero function has a local maximum and minimum at every point, depending on your definition of extrema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. First, for a local maxima I understand that: there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in \left(\frac{1}{2} - \delta, \frac{1}{2} + \delta\right)$ we have $f(x) \leq f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Do we agree on this definition? This is not true anymore if you get a negative constant. If $c < 0$ then $cf\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \leq cf(x)$ for every $x \in \left(\frac{1}{2} - \delta, \frac{1}{2} + \delta\right)$, so $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is not a local maxima of $cf$.

Comment: Thanks! So it is not a vector space.  Still I am curious about first property.

Comment: Your first statement is right, you can consider $x = \frac{1}{2}$ as a local maxima of $f \equiv 0$ (a trivial one). If $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is a local maxima of $f$ and of $g$ then, $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is a local maxima of $f + g$ (this is a direct application of the definition, since if $f(x) \leq f(\frac{1}{2})$ and $g(x) \leq g(\frac{1}{2})$ then $f(x) + g(x) \leq f(\frac{1}{2})  + g(\frac{1}{2})$).

Comment: Okay @ABP I got it :)

Comment: One more question, what if I have that $f$ has extrema at $x=1/2$ $( $ instead of maxima$)$. Then, zero function satisfies this property and also the property of scalar multiplication would be satisfied. I think the property of vector addition would not be satisfied in this case.

Comment: Take,  for instance, the functions $f, g$ such that $f(x) = x - \frac{1}{2}$ if $x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $g(x) = 0$ if $x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $g(x) = x- \frac{1}{2}$ if $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$. $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is a maximum point of $f$, a minimum of $g$, but $(f+g)(x) = x - \frac{1}{2}$ doesn't have neither a maximum nor a minimum at $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=sin(\pi x)\in V$ with maxima at $x=1/2$. For $k=-1$ in the field of reals, you have $kf(x)=-sin(\pi x)\notin V$ as it doesn't have maxima at $x=1/2$.